# zk wire multiple component

Tags: java, zk, zul

I'm trying to wire multiple `<button>` (ZUL tag) in a `List<Button>` field.
The purpose is to create multiple button to delete a user listed in a users list.
When someone click the button, the controller should handle an `onClick` event in order to call the model which will delete the user in the database.

The problems are:

1. I don't know if the `<button>`s are really wired.
2. The event handler declared with `@Listen("onClick = button")` is not working.

I don't know if the problem is the autowiring process or the event handling or both.

### backend.zul

Note that every row has a delete button with `id=""` matching the user ID. I need this in order to retrieve the user ID and delete the record with that ID. (Probably, is not the best way to do this, I'm sorry).

```
<?page title="Admin Backend" contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8"?>
<?init class="zk_auth.controller.AuthenticationInitiator"?>
<zk>
<window title="Admin Backend" border="normal" apply="zk_auth.controller.UsersListController">
<listbox id="AllUsers" emptyMessage="No user found">
    <listhead>
        <listheader label="Email" sort="auto" />
        <listheader label="Name" sort="auto" />
        <listheader label="Surname" sort="auto" />
        <listheader label="Role" sort="auto" />
        <listheader />
    </listhead>
    <template name="model">
        <listitem>
            <listcell label="${each.email}" />
            <listcell label="${each.name}" />
            <listcell label="${each.surname}" />
            <listcell label="${each.role}" />
            <listcell>
                <button label="Delete" sclass="delete_user" id="${each.id }" />
            </listcell>
        </listitem>
    </template>
</listbox>
<button label="Test" id="TestButton" />
</window>
</zk>
```

### zk_auth.controller.UsersListController

```
//Omitted imports for brevity

public class UsersListController extends SelectorComposer<Component>
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    // Not fucus on this.
    @Wire
    private Listbox AllUsers;

    // Here is the problem
    // This is the collection wired to all delete buttons.
    @Wire("button")
    private List<Button> DeleteButtons;

    // This button works!
    @Wire
    private Button TestButton;

    // Not focus on this. It lists all the users and it works.
    @Listen("onCreate = #AllUsers")
    public void ListAllUsers()
    {
        UserModel Users = new UserModel();
        List<User> UsersList = new ArrayList<User>(Users.getAllUsers());
        AllUsers.setModel(new ListModelList<User>(UsersList));
    }

    // Here is the problem
    // This doesn't work. I also tried
    // @Listen("onClick = button.delete_user")
    @Listen("onClick = button")
    public void DeleteUser(MouseEvent event)
    {
        Messagebox.show("It works!");
    }

    // This simple autowiring works. It targets only one button with id="TestButton".
    // No conflict with other onClick event handler, if you delete the test
    // nothing change.
    @Listen("onClick = #TestButton")
    public void Test()
    {
        Messagebox.show("It works!");
    }
}
```

### The result

[That's the rendered page, just for clarity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/msa44.png)

### Conclusion

The console log show me no error or warning. Did I make some mistake? How can i make fire multiple `onClick` events from multiple buttons and handle the event with one event handler?

Comment: Maybe you need to initialise `DeleteButtons` list?

Comment: Should I use an empty constructor (new DeleteButtons()) in the onCreate event handler?

Comment: In [ZK doc](https://www.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Developer%27s_Reference/MVC/Controller/Wire_Components#Wiring_a_Collection) says that 

"If the field starts null or uninitialized or wiring by method, SelectorComposer will try to construct an appropriate instance and assign to the field or pass to method call."

Comment: Is it possible to provide feedback on the answers please? Like this we know if we need to follow it up or not. Thx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

So, let me first explain why this doesn't work in the important phases for your case :
1. Create the page.
2. Wire all the components on the page.
3. Load the date and fill your data in the page.

Because you use `<template>` this is rendered in phase 3, so no more wiring will be done at that moment.

I have updated an [existing fiddle](http://zkfiddle.org/sample/1ssg7sd/114-MVC-Tutorial-Demo), run and press search twice. He will always give the size of the buttons in the List.
So, as you can see it keep's having 1 button.

### The solution :

Event forwarding like explained by cor3000 in [this forum topic](http://forum.zkoss.org/question/97727/listbox-with-delete-buttons/) :
Here is [a fiddle example](http://zkfiddle.org/sample/ct0cvg/1-forward-event).